# Can't load module XML::LibXML: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: perl-module

I want to upgrade perl from 5.8 to 5.16 on Linux Machine(32 bit). I could easily upgrade them (using perlbrew and CPAN).They work perfectly on Linux 32 bit machine.I don't want to disturb the system perl henceforth i used perbrew and copied the required modules in another path and they work fine. The problem i had encountered when i copied the the same on Linux x86_64. 64 bit did not support the 32 bit XML::LibXML module. I wanted to upgrade perl in such a way that it supports both the machines. Please suggest a solution for this error.

Can't load /opt/data/Linux2.X/lib/perl5/site/lib/i686-linux/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so' for module XML::LibXML: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /opt/data/Linux2.X/lib/perl5/lib/i686-linux/DynaLoader.pm line 190.

Thanks in Advance